# getting error distributionNotFound

Tags: python, celery

I have installed celeryD and redis on my system. when i am running the command using `celery`. iam getting the following error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celeryd", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-dateutil>=1.5,<2.0
```

what may be the possible reason??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a package called [python-dateutil](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) that isn't installed.

It should be available on the PYTHONPATH that's active when you call celeryd.

Python dateutil is installable from [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/).

Assuming you have [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) installed on your system, you can do so with this command:

```
$ pip install python-dateutil==1.5
```

Comment: you're solution is the right one. For some reason I had the python-dateutil 2.2 version.. I downgraded it to 1.5 to make it works.

Comment: Thanks!! actually now it's `2.2` in my case :) `pip install --ignore-installed python-dateutil==2.2`